# SubSonic - dividing up web.config

Tags: subsonic, web-config

I'm trying to divide up my web.config into multiple config files so that when I import the DLL to other projects, the .config files will also be imported.

Issue is with SubSonicService:

I've defined:
    **configSections**

```
  *section name="SubSonicService" type="SubSonic.SubSonicSection, SubSonic" requirePermission="false"/*

/**configsections**
```

But this doesn't allow me to use the configFile attribute later on in my web.config.

The error I get in the web.config is:

*The element 'SubSonicService' has incomplete content.  List of possible elements expected: 'providers'.*

Any tips?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you need to post more code...post as much of the .configs as you can without any sensitive data.

Comment: The problem seems to be that the defined secion name SubSonicService, when used below, is seen as an incomplete or tag:

SubSonicService configSource="SubSonic.config"

Am I missing something in the configsecions definition of SubSonicService (the code snip above is what I've got in that secion)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have this and it works.

**web.config**

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="SubSonicService" type="SubSonic.SubSonicSection, SubSonic" requirePermission="false"/>
   <!--Other Sections-->
  </configSections>

  <SubSonicService configSource="SubSonic.config"/>

  <!--Other Stuff-->
</configuration>
```

**SubSonic.config**

```
<SubSonicService defaultProvider="yadayada">
  <providers>
    <!--List Providers Hers-->
  </providers>
</SubSonicService>
```

I remember reading something about making sure SubSonicService was the first section in the configSections.

Comment: I'm using this in conjunction with SubSonic 2.2 and it works fine with SubSonicService not being the first section in configSections. Might be different with different versions.